# React-Native 'Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function!'

Tags: javascript, react-native, components

App.js renders a reusable external component `Fade` with its children component. The animation in `Fade` is executed when a children is confirmed with `{this.state.visible ? children : null}` in its render function. After debugging it, I believe the error is caused by the ternary operator, due to the way it is defined in the render function of `Fade`.

My issue is that I don't know how to correctly wrap this ternary operator in the render. I have tried `<Text>` and `<View>` without success. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

App.js render

```
<Container>
  <Fade visible={display.bus}> {renderIf(display.bus, <BusTemplate />)} </ Fade>
</Container>
```

Fade.js render

```
<Animated.View style={this.state.visible ? combinedStyle : containerStyle}>
  {this.state.visible ? children : null}
</Animated.View>
```

Bus.js render

```
<Container>
  <Image source={require("./scenerios/Bus.png")} style={styles.MainContainer}>
  </Image>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ciao Diego,
once I read this problem is related with the `if` check on an `undefined` var. It could be your case with `this.state.visible`.
Another chance is by wrapping your component in a `View` tag.
Here is the related issue with if checks:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13653
In case you already solved it, please let us know how

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will need to check that and let you know the results.